# Supported Problem types for Mosek Infeasibility Report

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, mosek

I was using Commercial Mosek via its Cvxpy interface. Specifically leveraging its **infeasibility report feature** for debugging of my infeasible problems.

Though it ran perfectly fine for sample LP problems but **failed on MILP problems** (i.e. no infeasibility report in the solver logs).

In the official documentation of Mosek [0], I couldn't find any specification on supported problem types for infeasibility report.

Kindly tell the supported problem types for infeasibility report.

(or does it work for all problem types?)

0 - https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/toolbox/debugging-infeas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infeasibility report is based on Farkas Lemma as discussed in

https://docs.mosek.com/whitepapers/infeas.pdf

Since Farkas Lemma does not apply to MILPs, then this report is not available for MILPs.

Comment: If you don't mind answering, which all problem types are supported for Infeasibility report?

Comment: @pqrz Continuous problems.

Comment: Is it some or all continuous problems - i.e. LP, QP, QCQP, SOCP, RSOCP, NLP ?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Can we safely assume all continuous problem types?

Comment: @pqrz All continuous problems.